# Checkbox using PHP and While loop in form

Tags: php, sql, checkbox, while-loop

I am trying to replicate this search that I do with a Select input but with a CheckBox for each select option but it doesn't work. It actually works with the select

```
<select required id="brand" name="brand" class="sm-form-control">
<option disabled value="">-- Brand--</option>
<?php
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($consult_brands)) {
echo "<option value='".$row["value"]."'>".$row["brand"]."</option>"; }
?>
</select>
```

Can you help me with the right way to do it in a Checkbox. The idea is that for every Brand I have in my SQL it creates a checkbox with a value and a Brand name.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Checkbox' aren't made with <option> elements. Make sure you are formatting your Checkbox HTML correctly. [Here's some additional information on Checkbox HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox).

Comment: What you're asking is off-topic for a few reasons. I think that now would be a good time for you to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Read through that and you'll see how things work here on Stack Overflow. It will give you a good idea as to how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help (you) have a better and positive experience here on Stack Overflow, which is what everybody wants and aims for.

Comment: I understand the problem just fine.

Answer (score 1):

### Goal HTML

```
<label for="Coke">Coke</label>
<input id="Coke" type="checkbox" name="brands[]" value="Coke">
<label for="Pepsi">Pepsi</label>
<input id="Pepsi" type="checkbox" name="brands[]" value="Pepsi">
<label for="Slice">Slice</label>
<input id="Slice" type="checkbox" name="brands[]" value="Slice">
<label for="Sprite">Sprite</label>
<input id="Sprite" type="checkbox" name="brands[]" value="Sprite">
```

Off the top of my head, you can use the array syntax for the `name` attribute to gather all of the brands in to one array element. Hence, your server-side code (`$_POST`, `filter_input_array(INPUT_POST ...)`) will have to handle an multi-dimensional array.

The key to doing a bunch of checkboxes dynamically in PHP is devising server side code to track the `checked` state of each one. This also requires you to understand that checkboxes that are not checked when the form is submitted are not successful (i.e. they do not provide an element a superglobal, or an element within an array within a superglobal).

Also, for accessibility reasons, you need to consider how to manage the `<label>`. Thus, the `<select>` control with `multiple` attribute might be something to consider, as then you will only have to deal with one label.

### General Heuristic

```
<?php
    $brands = ['Coke', 'Pepsi', 'Slice', 'Sprite'];
    $checkboxes = [];

    foreach ($brands as $key => $brand) {
        $checkboxes[] = '<label for="' . $brand . '">' . $brand . '</label><input id="' . $brand . '" type="checkbox" name="brands[]" value="' . $brand . '">"';
    }

    $checkboxes = implode("\n", $checkboxes);
?>

<form action="/search.php" method="post">
    <?= $checkboxes; ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

*Missing* here is a spot for the `checked` attribute to promote form stickiness.
Simply add that processing logic to your form handler and track which brands were selected. Then, run your loop logic as follows.

```
<?php
    function isChecked($name, array $checkableControls)
    {
        if (in_array($name, $checkableControls)) {
            return ' checked="checked" ';
        }

        return '';
    }

    $brands = ['Coke', 'Pepsi', 'Slice', 'Sprite']; // From database

    // $submitted = $_POST['brands'];
    $submitted = ['Coke', 'Slice'];  // From the user during HTTP POST request

    $brandResults = search($submitted);
    $htmlBrandRecords = formatResults($brandResults);

    $checkboxes = [];

    foreach ($brands as $key => $brand) {
        $checkboxes[] = '<label for="' . $brand . '">' . $brand . '</label><input id="' . $brand . '" type="checkbox" name="brands[]" . isChecked($brand, $submitted) . value="' . $brand . '">';
    }

    $checkboxes = implode("\n", $checkboxes);
?>
<section id="search">
    <form action="/search.php" method="post">
        <?= $checkboxes; ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    <div id="records">
        <?= $htmlBrandRecords; ?>
        <!-- Place your results here via PHP. -->
        <!-- Alternatively, send JSON to the user-agent. -->
    </div>
<section>
```

### Conclusions

1. This can be easily edited to work with associative arrays.
2. Submitting number codes  (1, 2, 3, 4) instead of text (Coke, Slice) may be better (and more secure in the long run).
3. Check encoding, filter, and validate all user inputs. Properly escape any user input as it changes contexts (PHP -> SQL, PHP -> HTML, etc ...).
4. Never directly place user submitted data into your forms.
5. Organize your code into classes. It will save you time.
6. Using a heredoc can save you from doing expensive contatenations.
7. Gather up all the lables and inputs before sending them through the output buffer.
8. This is a barebones solution, not exactly how I would do this.
9. You can track the state of any HTML attribute (`disabled`, `class`) like this, allowing you to manipulate your form by disabling/enabling controls, or showing or hiding form elements by adding or removing CSS classes from the `class` attribute.
10. This can help you make truly progressively enhanced forms, that rival your JavaScript creations (well, almost ;-).
11. Doing MVC? You can make HTML views to complement your JSON views for forms.

Comment: Don't use `\n` , use PHP constant `PHP_EOL` instead for cross-platform compatibility. Also, for checkbox input, if `checked` attribute exists, it will be checked, no matter what value assigned to it, e.g. `checked="false"`. This is a very common mistake.

Comment: `PHP_EOL` is also displayed as a new line. It might be `\n` or `\r\n`, depends on the operating platform. For the attribute issue, please refer to HTML spec / MDN documentation.

Comment: All of the outputted content is destined for web browsers in this case. The platform is the user-agent, and in this case, "\n" will work in the relevant circumstances because its context is "view source" in the browser.

PHP_EOL is for operating system level compliance, which does not effect the context of the user-agent in this case. Try it. You will see. While the newline is not required for HTML, it simply makes viewing source easier.

I know what the W3C spec for HTML5 says. What it does not say is being consistent means something, but I say it does mean something.

Comment: @Raptor https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/the-input-element.html#attr-input-checked

Comment: The syntax of the `checked` attribute is my only concern. I am focused on server-side issues right now, but I did err in returning `checked` instead of the entire syntax `checked="checked"`. Although, you can check a checkable control with less. Do let me know if you have a fiddle for `PHP_EOL` and the "view source" thing.

Comment: For the `PHP_EOL` (stated as official doc as *The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform.*), it cannot be tested via simple fiddle, as it involves multiple operating systems & web servers. I agree that from the source code point of view, it probably will look like the same (as the browser will handle the visual changes), but when you run it in CLI / write a file, you might find a difference.

Comment: I agree. CLI representations are a different story. In this case, use `\n` to prevent `\r\n` from ever being generated. It's one thing to have five checkboxes / radios / options, but a pizza ordering site may have many more controls to generate in a sychronous view. No biggie, but ultimately, someone is paying for those bytes (space, time, compute, network) that are not required. Heck, you could join on the empty string, but one must fight battles worth fighting, and wonder what would make life easier. ;-)

Comment: Hello! Thanks for you reply. I just have one more question. How can i replace the $brands = ['Coke', 'Pepsi', 'Slice', 'Sprite']; with something like $brands 
 = [$brandsql]; because i have alredy stored all the values in that $brandsql but it just showed me the last value with a checkbox and not all the 50 values. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following solution:

```
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='brands[]' value='".$row["value"]."'>".$row["brand"]."<br>";
    }
```

Comment: You are missing the labels.

Comment: Also don't need the closing option tag.

Comment: @Jonathan ... Good observation. I missed that. I have fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge ... We do not need labels here. The brand names are already being outputted.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge ... Okay. I agree with you. Needed is a strong word. Thanks.